# jQuery SO Vote-Object and Scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, greasemonkey

This is a javascript question. The fact that it mentions this website is irrelevant. This *does not* belong on meta.

---

I'm working on a [Greasemonkey script to auto-load additional pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8472/script-infinite-scrolling-of-answers) of answers onto the first page of answers here at Stackoverflow as you scroll. This is working well. I want to maintain the ability to up-vote/down-vote the loaded items, so I'm using $.live(), which is also working fine.

My problem is that the vote-object, used by SO, is not found within the scope of the $.live() method, or atleast I think that is the problem.

```
$(".vote-up").live("click", function(D){
  vote.up($(D.target));
});

$.get("/questions/1151074", function(data){
  $("div.answer", data).insertAfter(".answer:last");
});
```

That's  bit of sample code you can paste into your firebug console to test. You can see that vote, in the context of the .live() call is not accessible. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try `unsafeWindow.vote.up()`?

Comment: @crescentfresh That seems to have gotten me one step closer. The votes are binding now, but it's a very brittle interaction. Thank you though.

Comment: Yeah, that's just how it's done with Greasemonkey. It's a security measure of sorts. Annoying when you forget though.

Comment: Care to post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `unsafeWindow.vote.up()`.

See [the docs](http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow). It's a security measure of sorts. Annoying when you forget though.